# How to open subview under textfield in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

On click textfield, subview is opened over root view. I want to open the view under the textfield.

My subview code is bellow. **Category** is my **ViewController** which is opened as subview. Problem is that **Category** subview open over root view.

```
let popUpVc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Category") as! Category        
popUpVc.categoryDelegate = self
self.addChildViewController(popUpVc)
popUpVc.view.frame = self.view.frame
self.view.addSubview(popUpVc.view)
```

Please help me.

Comment: `under the textfield` means below textfield like autocomplete?

Comment: @ Pratik Prajapati textfield look like drop down list. when i click textfield , it will subview will open bellow the textfield clicked not over whole page page.

Comment: `popUpVc.view.frame = self.view.frame` cause your popup size same as your root. You should calculate `popUpVc.view.frame` your self to position under texftfield. the easiest way is you create container view under textfield on storyboard using constraint (you can show/hide if you want), then set `popUpVc.view.frame = containerView.frame`. I know its not elegant X)